# Java EntityManager/hibernate saves old values of the object

Tags: java, swing, hibernate

I'm having issues with doing proper save in hibernate/entity manager in swing desktop application. I have a method that counts proper logouts from application via call to webservice. Webservice method looks like this:

```
public void setLoggodOutCount(User user){              
        user.setLoggedOutCount(12);
        em.merge(user);
}
```

After calling this webservice method my program exits. Then when I look at my server logs I can see that there was two updates executed. One with good value=12 and one with prev value=11. Sometimes there are in good order, sometimes not. What can I do to force my update being executed last?

Comment: Please clarify: Who is using hibernate? The swing app, the web server or both? What other places interact with the EntityManager?

Comment: webservice is using hibernate, I have there multiple Facade classes and all derives from Base Facade that have following code: `@PersistenceContext(unitName = "myPu")
    protected EntityManager em;`

Comment: If the values `11`, `12`, etc (loggedOutCount) is passed from the Swing app to the webservice, then it is almost impossible to achieve what you are looking for. The update requests from the Swing app cannot be synchronized.

Comment: nope they are set in webservice count and I never pass 11, I only pass 12. 11 is from old object state I guess...

Comment: Are you sure the Swing app's request always reaches the server? Did you put a break point in `setLoggedOutCount` method and saw that `em.merge(user);` is executed with the right number? (I assume that `12` isn't really hard-coded in the method's implementation ;-) ).

Comment: Could be a bug on your swing calling the function twice, with 11 and 12. Or could be a bug on your webservice transaction boundaries / session flushing. Debug both setLoggedOutCount on swing and hibernate transaction using `org.hibernate.transaction` logger